# Getting Flywayautoconfiguration error when upgrading to flyway 10 and spring boot 3.1.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I am trying to use latest version of flyway-core 10.0.0 in my pom.xml, with latest spring boot version 3.1.5 but when I run my test using flyway I get below error:-

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.configureProperties(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:254)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.licenseKey(java.lang.String)'
```

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/sx8428/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.1.5/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class
```

The called method's class, org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/sx8428/.m2/repository/org/flywaydb/flyway-core/10.0.0/flyway-core-10.0.0.jar!/org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration: file:/C:/Users/sx8428/.m2/repository/org/flywaydb/flyway-core/10.0.0/flyway-core-10.0.0.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration and org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot has to be updated to work with Flyway v10, it is on their radar: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38164

Comment: @ AlistairW The above GitHub issue shows as closed but I don't see any change in spring boot maven repo. Does it takes time to sink here? Or they will release it in a different version maybe? mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot

Comment: @ShubhamShekhar it's marked as completed because they've done & merged the change but it hasn't made it into a release yet. It will most likely be included in the next one

Answer (score 1):

Encountering the same issue！

flywaydb 10.0.0
spring boot  3.1.5.
mysql 8.1

ps：  flywaydb 9.22.3 is ok。

Comment: Yes But flyway 10 has a feature which allows to use all version of mysql including 5.7, so I need to use 10 version somehow for my project requirement